# Modified code and now it doesn't run, receiving syntax error

Tags: android

So I had this code and was trying to edit it to add an extra button and now it doesn't want to run. It is identical to what I had before. I deleted the new code but now this code doesn't want to run. Any tips? I'm getting errors on the moveTo(activity) variables. Does it something to do with the semicolons and brackets? I'm really confused as to why it isn't working.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button B3;
private Button B4;
private Button B5;
private Button B6;
private Button B7;
private Button B25;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    B3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    B3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moveToDanceScheduleMenu();
        }
    });

    B4 = findViewById(R.id.button10);
    B4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moveToWhatsOn();
        }
    });

    B5 = findViewById(R.id.button11);
    B5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moveToMainResultsMenu();
        }
    });

    B6 = findViewById(R.id.button12);
    B6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moveToSponsorsMenu();
        }
    });

    B7 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
    B7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moveToRulesAndRegs();
        }
    });

    B25 = findViewById(R.id.button18);
    B25.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moveTomusic_submission();

        }
    });

private void moveTomusic_submission () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, music_submission.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void moveToDanceScheduleMenu () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, DanceScheduleMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void moveToWhatsOn () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, WhatsOn.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void moveToMainResultsMenu () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainResultsMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void moveToSponsorsMenu () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, SponsorsMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void moveToRulesAndRegs () {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, RulesAndRegs.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }}}
```

Comment: which syntax error it gives, and where?

Comment: Basically the errors are after each moveTo variables. It asks for semicolons and expressions.

Comment: ok, I already see where. You didn't close the `onCreate` method bracket, and therefore - declared *method inside a method*

Comment: So where would I add this bracket? After which part?

Comment: Mate your a legend. All fixed. Thanks